# TCP/IP connection to the host localhost port 1487 has failed - Linux 32 bit

Tags: java, sql-server, linux, tcp

I try to connect to a mySql localhost database. I checked the port 1487 and is open for connection. Many solutions suggest to open SQL Server Configuration Manager, but there is no such thing in Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to install  Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server on Linux, but it's only for 64 bit systems. I use eclipse to write my java code:

```
    String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1487;user=sa;password=1234";
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
    if (conn != null) {
             System.out.println("Connected");
    }
```

**Error:**

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host SQL2008, port 1487 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.
```

Comment: The question is tagged mysql but you are trying to connect to a microsoft sqlserver?

Comment: You can't use a Microsoft SQL server driver to connect to a MySQL server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server is a database produced by Microsoft based on a Sybase database. I believe these have compatible SQL connectors. Note: I don't believe SQL Server runs on Linux.

However, MySQL is a completely different database.  As such I suggest using the MySQL JDBC drivers, or the [MariaDB Connector/J](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/about-mariadb-connector-j/) and URL to connect to MySQL as this is more likely to work.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

The example it gives is

```
conn =
   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?" +
                               "user=minty&password=greatsqldb");
```

Note: how this mentions `mysql` not `sqlserver`

Comment: In my experience the MariaDB Connector/J is better, and has a sane license (i.e. not GPL)

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the command to display the tables of the database?

Comment: @yasuo do you mean `SHOW TABLES`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html That's what google thinks anyway ;)